# Cannot read property of 'onOverviewChange' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple application where I have a App Component (Parent) and an Edit Component (Child).  What I'm trying to do is update the state when the fields in the Edit component are changed.  However when I make this change I get the error  Cannot read property 'onOverviewChange' of undefined
at onChange (bundle.js:57164).

```
export default class OverviewEditPane extends React.Component {  

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  autoBind(this);
}


onOverviewChange(event) {
  let state = this.state;
  let field = event.target.name; 
  let value = event.target.value;
  state[field] = value;
  this.setState({state});

}

render () {
  return (
          <table>
            <FormFields>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.overview.map(function(P){return <TextInput size='small'  key={P.id} id={P.id} value={P.FName} onChange={() => this.onOverviewChange.bind(this)}  />;})}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.overview.map(function(P){return <TextInput size='small' key={P.id} id={P.id} value={P.LName} onChange={() => this.onOverviewChange.bind(this)} />;})}</td>
                </tr> ...
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I appear to be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you have done in `onChange` is not the correct way also in the call back method of `map` can be written as arrow function .Try using the following way

```
export default class OverviewEditPane extends React.Component {  

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  autoBind(this);
  this.onOverviewChange = this.onOverviewChange.bind(this)
}


onOverviewChange(event) {
  let state = this.state;
  let field = event.target.name; 
  let value = event.target.value;
  state[field] = value;
  this.setState({state});

}

render () {
  return (
          <table>
            <FormFields>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.overview.map((P) =>{return <TextInput size='small'  key={P.id} id={P.id} value={P.FName} onChange={this.onOverviewChange} />;})}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.overview.map((P) =>{return <TextInput size='small' key={P.id} id={P.id} value={P.LName} onChange={this.onOverviewChange} />;})}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
 )
            }
 }
```

Comment: Had to change {this.props.overview.map(function(P){... to this.props.overview.map((P) = >{.....   Thanks this seem to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving a regular function to your `map`. Either bind that as well, or use an arrow function instead.

`() => this.onOverviewChange.bind(this)` will create a new function that returns a function. Make sure you invoke `this.onOverviewChange` inside the new function instead.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    {this.props.overview.map(P => {
      return (
        <TextInput
          size="small"
          key={P.id}
          id={P.id}
          value={P.FName}
          onChange={(e) => this.onOverviewChange(e)}
        />
      );
    })}
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    {this.props.overview.map(P => {
      return (
        <TextInput
          size="small"
          key={P.id}
          id={P.id}
          value={P.LName}
          onChange={(e) => this.onOverviewChange(e)}
        />
      );
    })}
  </td>
</tr>
```

You must also make sure you don't mutate `state` in your event handler. You could write it like this instead:

```
onOverviewChange(event) {
  this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly is causing that bug but the following code corrections may mitigate it:

1. Change `onChange={() => this.onOverviewChange.bind(this)}` to `onChange={this.onOverviewChange}`
2. Change `state[field] = value; this.setState({state});` to `this.setState({[field]: value})`

Comment: Thanks for the response but after making the first change the component won't load.

Comment: It should load actually. You must be making some kinda mistake. Even the answer you have approved has implemented the same code. Please re-check.

Comment: Please see comment above.